# Fancybox Gallery Navigation Not Working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox, gallery, fancybox-3

I'm using Fancybox for photo galleries on multiple WordPress websites.

Since upgrading to the newest Fancybox code, I'm having a problem with Fancybox gallery navigation not working.

The photos open perfectly, but they are not linked together.

Here's the simple code I'm using within the head:

```
<!-- Fancybox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

The galleries are generated using WordPress default media gallery shortcode.

This is my fancybox call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".gallery-icon a").fancybox({ 
        animationEffect : 'fade'
    }).attr('rel', 'group1');
});
</script>
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to assign rel="group1" to the links. I've also tried the attribute "data-fancybox-group".

Neither are working.

Here's the link:

[Demo Website](http://d2demos.com/usa/photos/inground-pools/)

Any ideas on how to get the navigation buttons appearing and link these photos as a gallery?

Could it be a jQuery version issue?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Fancybox support? They're the ones who will know best if there is a compatibility issue between versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Galleries are created by adding the same `data-fancybox` attribute value.

For example:

```
$(".gallery-icon a").fancybox({ 
  animationEffect : 'fade'
}).attr('data-fancybox', 'group1');
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EwpOxE?editors=1010